# How would I create software that reads pages in an open Chrome window?

Tags: windows, google-chrome

So I guess this is a kind of vague question, but I only need a vague answer.

Background: I have a ton of experience with the logical aspect of programming (which I picked up from first writing Lua in a few games, then from OOP in Unity3D), but very little experience with practical software development in Windows. I'm not sure what language to use, or even where to start with what I'm trying to do.

Imagine there is a Chrome window open. It's displaying a page that updates itself often. How would I write a program that constantly reads the Chrome window for changes in the webpage, then displays information in its own window? I can definitely figure out what I'll need to do once the program is getting that input correctly, but I can't imagine the steps I would need to take to read the Chrome page like that.

If there's no clear answer, then simply names and explanations that I can google as search terms would be perfect.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to hijack AJAX requests being made on a page. If so, let me know, we can chat and figure out what you're trying to do, then come up with a good Q&A pair. I understand, of course, if you no longer have any interest, given the age of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Webscraping might be the way to go, I think this example speaks to what you are trying to achieve: http://newcoder.io/scrape/intro/

Otherwise I would use javascript to write a script that looks for text/html changes in the page and displays the results in a pop up window (if that suits).
Greasemonkey would probably come in handy. Read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey

Comment: Thanks for the helpful links. Webscraping is close to what I'm trying to do, but not quite. I _don't_ want the program to access the internet and collect things from webpages by itself. I want the program to sit in the background and collect data from a Chrome page as I browse it manually.

Comment: Ahh maybe you could look into a chrome extension? Try Page Monitor - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-monitor/pemhgklkefakciniebenbfclihhmmfcd?hl=en

Comment: Thanks again, but it's not quite what I need. I don't need to be notified when the webpage changes. I am trying to write my own program that will run while I do a specific activity, and collect changes in the webpage as I do that activity. All I need help with is how to figure out how to allow the program to look at the Chrome process and get the active page from it. Maybe it's a windows API thing? Maybe there's a file somewhere that's being stored locally? If I can figure out how to retrieve that page, then that's all I need! (and there is more that I will need to write on my own)